# What is expected value of three variables?

Tags: calculus, probability, random-variables

I have an individual $x=(x_1x_2x_3x_4)$ (for example $x_1=1111$). Now, given a set (4 individuals) of individuals such as

```
Individual 1: 1111
Individual 2: 0101
Individual 3: 1011
Individual 4: 0011
```

It can easily see that 
$$p(x_1=0)=1/2,p(x_1=0)=1/2,p(x_2=0)=1/2,p(x_2=0)=1/2$$

We also have

$p(x_1=0,x_2=0)=1/4,p(x_1=0,x_2=1)=1/4, p(x_1=1,x_2=0)=1/4,p(x_1=1,x_2=1)=1/4$

and so on..

Now, I assume that I group (merge) two bits $(x_1,x_2)$ in one variable called $y$,
How to compute

1. Probability of $p(x_3=0,y)=?,p(x_4=0,y)=?$
2. Expected value of $E[x_3y],E[x_4y]$
3. Covariance $COV[x_3y]$

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you say "merge into y", does it mean that y, the string(say 01), can appear anywhere in the string?

Comment: As I think merge here is $y=\{x_1x_2\}$. That mean it will appear as string 00,01,10,11

Comment: I don't understand how $P(x_1=0)=1/2$. Isn't $x_1$ the string $1111$ of four binary digits? Also, I think you have a typo in the probabilities (should probably be $x_1=1$ and $x_2=1$ the second time around).

Comment: @HowDoIMath $P(x_1=0)$ that mean it will find how many bit at first position of all individual equal 1. In here we can see that $x_1=1$ will appears in individual 1 and individual 3. Then prob. of $x_1=1$ is 2 divides to total of number individual is 4

Comment: Ok. Then you are looking for e.g. $P(x_3=0,y=(1,0))$? This is equal to $P(x_3=0,x_1=1,x_2=0)=1/8$.

Comment: I am looking 3 problems. Let see my question. Thanks